# oracle dynamic sql using params with brackets as table name

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql, using-statement

I have a table in my schema with brackets in its name (that's a legacy, cannot be modified):

```
CREATE TABLE "Addresses"
    ("ID"                        NUMBER(*,0) ,
    "FullAddress"                  NVARCHAR2(100),
    "HomeNum"                      NVARCHAR2(25),
    "StreetName"                   NVARCHAR2(50)
)
```

So what I want is to have an ability to update this table via dynamic sql. That's how I attempt to do that:

```
DECLARE 
  sql_upd_statement VARCHAR2(500) := '';
  table_name VARCHAR2(20) := '"Addresses"';
  column_name VARCHAR2(20) := '"FullAddress"';
BEGIN

   --no rows will be updated, just a sample 
   sql_upd_statement := 'UPDATE stm.:1 SET :2 = SUBSTR( :2, 2 ) WHERE :2 IS NOT NULL AND :2 IS NULL';

   dbms_output.put_line( sql_upd_statement );

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  sql_upd_statement USING IN table_name, column_name;

END;
```

Please, tell me, is it possible to reach what I want via dynamic sql? Tried to set 'table_name', 'column_name' values without brackets - still no luck.

Comment: I don't see any brackets in your table name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema object names cannot be passed using bind variables, they need to be literals.

```
sql_upd_statement := 'UPDATE stm.'||table_name||' SET '||column_name||' = SUBSTR( '||column_name||', 2 ) WHERE '||column_name||' IS NOT NULL AND '||column_name||' IS NULL';
```

Comment: Thanks, there was hope that I just missed smth. Ok, then :)